# Save gensim doc2vec model in google drive

Tags: nlp, gensim

I want to save my Gensim doc2vec model into my notebooks folder which is in my google drive but when I run the model.save('doc2vec_model') method it is saving the model somewhere else.

```
  fname = get_tmpfile(f"doc2vec_{sub}_model_without_tuning")
  model.save(fname)
```

The model is stored the /tmp folder.
[tmp folder of my drive.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/waFnh.png)
please help me to save my model inside my drive/notebooks folder

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Gensim utility function `get_tmpfile()`, you are asking the library to give you a file-path inside whatever directory is customarily used for temporary files. So, it's doing what you've asked.

The `.save()` method will take whatever path you provide, as a plain string, so if the place you want to save the model is available as a local file path, just use that path.

(Keep in mind that for most models of usual size, the `.save()` operation will write multiple related files, which kust be kept together to re-load properly.)

Comment: could you please write the code of saving the model in my desired folder with the model name f"doc2vec_{sub}_model_without_tuning". It will be great help for me

Comment: No. What happens when you just try using that filename without the unnecessary `get_tmpfile()`? Where does it land? What *is* the current working director of the Python process where you're running your code?